# Add new Plugin or Delete option Not Showing and Also Theme delete option not showing

Tags: plugins, themes

Recently, I install wordpress a website. but after installing wordpress and theme I can't show theme delete option, plug in delete option, add new plug in option, add new theme option. I took this step but Not working these

1. Deactive all the plugins and activate them again
2. Change the theme Ocean Wp to twenty twenty three
3. Change two lines of code from wp-config.php ( true to false). even delete these line too.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Things to check: Is this a multisite installation? Are you sure you've got the appropriate privileges to do these things? Is there a plugin installed that affects the privileges or hides buttons? Are the permissions set correctly in the filesystem to allow uploading or deleting?

Answer (score 0):

In your `wp-config.php` file, take a look if you have these lines of code:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
```

These settings might impact your ability to edit files and make modifications.